# Gets last digit of a number

Tags: java, return, digits

I need to define the last digit of a number assign this to value. 
After this, return the last digit.

My snippet of code doesn't work correctly...

**Code:**

```
public int lastDigit(int number) {
    String temp = Integer.toString(number);
    int[] guess = new int[temp.length()];
    int last = guess[temp.length() - 1];

    return last;
}
```

**Question:**

- How to solve this issue?

Comment: Why does it not work? Do you get the wrong value or an exception?

Comment: You're creating an empty array when you create "guess". You need to populate it with the characters of temp too. The right way would be to use %10 as most people have answered below. But to fix your code without changing the approach, you can do something like `Integer.parseInt(temp.substring(temp.length()-1))`

Answer (score 169, accepted):

Just return `(number % 10)`; i.e. take the modulus. This will be much faster than parsing in and out of a string.

If `number` can be negative then use `(Math.abs(number) % 10);`

Comment: What is Java's semantics of the % operator when the left operand is negative? Chances are that it will not return the last digit.

Comment: @Kaz: That's an important point: %10 does not extract the last digit for a negative number. Thank you. I've amended.

Comment: What if number is null?

Comment: OP has a primitive type for number: so can't be null.

Answer (score 18):

Below is a simpler solution how to get the last digit from an `int`:

```
public int lastDigit(int number) { return Math.abs(number) % 10; }
```

Comment: You can be first to get it right for when `number` is negative.

Answer (score 8):

Use

```
int lastDigit = number % 10.
```

Read about Modulo operator: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Or, if you want to go with your `String` solution

```
String charAtLastPosition = temp.charAt(temp.length()-1);
```

Answer (score 5):

No need to use any `strings`.Its over burden.

```
int i = 124;
int last= i%10;
System.out.println(last);   //prints 4
```

Answer (score 2):

Without using **'%'**.

```
public int lastDigit(int no){
    int n1 = no / 10;
    n1 = no - n1 * 10;
    return n1;
}
```

Comment: What would be the point? I only see needless complication.

Answer (score 1):

You have just created an empty integer array. The array `guess` does not contain anything to my knowledge. The rest you should work out to get better.

Answer (score 1):

Your array don't have initialization. So it will give default value Zero.
You can try like this also

```
String temp = Integer.toString(urNumber);
System.out.println(temp.charAt(temp.length()-1));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(lastDigit(2347));
}

public static int lastDigit(int number)
{
    //your code goes here. 
    int last = number % 10;

    return last;
}
```

### 0/p:

7

Answer (score 0):

here is your method

```
public int lastDigit(int number)
{
    //your code goes here. 
    int last =number%10;
    return last;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use StringUtils, in case you need string result:

```
String last = StringUtils.right(number.toString(), 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another interesting way to do it which would also allow more than just the last number to be taken would be:

```
int number = 124454;
int overflow = (int)Math.floor(number/(1*10^n))*10^n;

int firstDigits = number - overflow;
//Where n is the number of numbers you wish to conserve</code>
```

In the above example if n was 1 then the program would return: 4

If n was 3 then the program would return 454

Answer (score -1):

Although the best way to do this is to use % if you insist on using strings this will work

```
public int lastDigit(int number)
{
return Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(Integer.toString(number).charAt(Integer.toString(number).length() - 1)));
}
```

but I just wrote this for completeness. Do not use this code. it is just awful.