# Find first non zero number in N! in Java

Tags: java, string, math, biginteger

How to find first non zero number of the factorial of N. N can be in range from 1 to 2147483647. The output return an integer number.

EX:

```
findFirstNoneZeroNumberOfTheFactorial(4) = 4; // because 4! = 24
findFirstNoneZeroNumberOfTheFactorial(5) = 2; // because 5! = 120
```

here is my code:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Solution {
    public static int findFirstNoneZeroNumberOfTheFactorial(int n) {
        BigInteger fact = null;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            fact = fact.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
        }
        String sFact = String.valueOf(fact);
        for (int i = sFact.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (sFact.charAt(i) != '0') {
                int result = Character.getNumericValue(sFact.charAt(i));
                return result;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(Solution.findFirstNoneZeroNumberOfTheFactorial(4));
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work!!

Comment: Do you mean first non-zero *digit?*

Comment: Yup, find first non-zero digit from right to left.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your initialization is not correct.

`BigInteger fact = BigInteger.ONE;`

> This is not optimal. 
>   If you just need the single last non-zero digit just keep track only the last non zero digit not the whole multiplied number.

```
let's do some math
x     x!      last-nonzero-digit(x * last-nonzero-digit)
1     1             1*1        => 1
2     2             2*1 = 2    => 2
3     6             3*2 = 6    => 6 
4     24            6*4 = 2(4) => 4
5     120           4*5 = (2)0 => 2 
6     720           2*6 = 1(2) => 2
7     5040          2*7 = 1(4) => 4
```

WHY DO I HAVE TO CALCULATE THE WHOLE MULTIPLICATION?

Just keep the last non zero digit.

Comment: Nice!! I got it!! Thank a lot @Uma Kanth!!

Comment: @samgak True. That's much more optimial. But I don't find a repeating cycle.

Comment: @UmaKanth there isn't a pattern, my mistake:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100544/repeating-last-non-zero-digits-of-factorial

Comment: @UmaKanth According to your approach, We need to have accountability for the last digit of the previous number. How is that better than brute force?

Comment: @FallAndLearn brute force needs to calculate the whole factorial. 1000! factorial has 2568 digits in it. Which needs a lot of computational power, where as at max 9*9 has only 2 digits in it.

Comment: I got your point. I am facing difficulty on analysing how to implement it.

Comment: @FallAndLearn http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17144997/gets-last-digit-of-a-number this should help.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to initialize your `fact` variable, which results in a `NullPointerException`.

Change

```
BigInteger fact = null;
```

to

```
BigInteger fact = BigInteger.ONE;
```

Output for `System.out.println(Solution.findFirstNoneZeroNumberOfTheFactorial(4));` :

```
4
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of converting it to a String check for the module operation and if it is different from zero this is your answer, otherwise divide by 10.

```
public static int findFirstNoneZeroNumberOfTheFactorial(int n) {
    long fact = 1L;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        fact = fact * i;
    }
    while (fact > 0) {
        long module = fact % 10;
        if (module != 0) {
            return module;
        }
        fact = fact / 10;
    }
    return -1;

}
```

Comment: But this way, it doesn't work with a big number like 99! .

Comment: It is not necessary for this problem. long is big enough and it is faster and less expensive in memory

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the question. N can be in range from 1 to 2147483647, not N! So correct, you have to use BigInteger

Comment: It is possible to replace with BigInteger rewriting % and / operators with the corresponding mod and divide methods

Comment: Anyway, tks for your answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

Is this right??

```
public static int number(int n) {
        int LastNoneZero = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            LastNoneZero *= i;
            if (LastNoneZero > 9) {
                String s = Integer.toString(LastNoneZero);
                if (s.charAt(1) == '0') {
                    LastNoneZero = Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(0));
                } else {
                    LastNoneZero = Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(1));
                }
            }
        }
        return LastNoneZero;
    }
```