# Int version of Id.CharAt()

Tags: java, char, int

I'm trying to create a username which contains the last 2 digits of the person's birth year, but it says an int can't be dereferenced. What would be the int version of `id.charAt()`? This is a section of my code.

```
Scanner by = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.println ("Please enter your birth year:");
int byear = by.nextInt();
if (byear >= 2008){
//the next 2 lines are what I'm having problems with:
    char yeara = byear.charAt(2);
    char yearb = byear.charAt(3);
//the 2 lines above ^^^
} else {
    System.out.println ("Sorry, you're too young to use this website");
}
```

Comment: Note that you'd need `byear <= 2008` if you want somebody to be older than 10 (ish). Otherwise you'd allow people younger than that age, and the message should be `too old to use this website`.

Comment: I am surprised that I can't find a duplicate for this... This seems so trivial that it must have been asked before...

Comment: @Sweeper not sure how hard you looked... searching for "site:stackoverflow.com last two digits of int java" showed up lots of results.

Comment: found another: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17144997/gets-last-digit-of-a-number

Comment: @AndyTurner ah I was tricked by the title. I couldn’t find anything about a charAt method for ints

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The last two digits can be obtained with:

```
int lastTwo = byear % 100;
```

Of course, if you need them separately, some extra work is required:

```
int last = byear % 10;
int beforeLast = (byear/10) % 10;
```

Comment: Perhaps worth mentioning that `charAt` is a method on `String`; you can convert the int to a String if you wanted to do it that way.

Comment: @AndyTurner that's true, but I expect that to be less efficient.

Comment: Sure, I wouldn't do it like that. But it might be useful to OP to point out why what she tried didn't work.

Comment: @Eran thnks! The only problem I'm getting with this is if the 1st of the 2 digits is a 0, the application does not use it (eg. username ABrown03 would not show up, but it would be ABrown3). Do you know how I'd fix this? :)

Comment: @TVlassi in this case I would like to use `String twoLastDigits = String.valueOf(byear).replaceAll(".*(\\d{2})$", "$1");`

Comment: @YCF_L That worked! Thank you! :)